# Please help to troubleshoot the issue with Inspiron 8600 laptop

Tags: video, display, dell-inspiron, laptop-repair

I have a Dell Inspiron 8600 laptop which display stopped working all of the sudden. It started to show a purple fog pattern along with some color vertical lines. I talked to Dell support and they told me that is a screen gone bad and I should get a new one which I did.
But surprisingly the new display won't work either! The pattern on the screen is different but still no picture. So I tried to connect the old display to another laptop (Lenovo Z61) and it turns out it works just fine with it!
So please help me to identify the cause of the issue. I think it could be a video card but the external display works flawlessly. I appreciate your thoughts about it so I won't need to buy spares which I don't need.

Thank you!

P.S. Please do not suggest to contact Dell support again.

Comment: Dell Support can't do more than give advice based on what you present to them, they can give far more accurate advice if they have the ability to inspect your laptop to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not the screen, then it is the graphics processor or the path between it and your panel. If this is soldered to the mainboard you could try to let Dell replace the mainboard, which can cost a lot if the guarantee has passed. If it is a separate graphics card you might be able to replace that for a reasonable price. Maybe you should consider to buy a new laptop after all...